# Ubuntu 18.04 server upgrade failing

Tags: apt, upgrade, 18.04

I run an Ubuntu 18.04 server which I manage via SSH.  After having initiated an `apt update && apt upgrade` this morning I forgot about it and the shell session ended when my laptop powered down.  When I tried the update again I was initially told

> Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/)

etc which I dealt with using the tips provided in [this AU thread.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)  However, that still did not allow me to proceed with a system update so I rebooted the server.  Following the reboot I ran the upgrade again. This time round the system went a bit further but then came back with the messages

> APT had planned for dpkg to do more than it reported back (0 vs 4).
>      Affected packages: linux-image-4.15.0-24-generic:amd64

What can I do to fully recover from these issues?

Comment: That sounds worse than it probably is - try `dpkg --configure -a`; if that doesn't turn up any problems you're good to go.

Comment: Please edit your question to add complete output of each command you try - edited summaries are much less helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix unmet dependencies for udev:amd64 error on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097066/how-to-fix-unmet-dependencies-for-udevamd64-error-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 0):

I've reported it as a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1780020